# Adding second functionality to a single button

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a button which I want to toggle between two 'functionalities.' I want it to toggle my menu open and close

I want to add `onclick="openNav()"` on first click and then `onclick="closeNav()"` on the second
html

```
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" onclick="openNav()"></button>
```

I'm not sure the best way to do this, the code works if they are on two separate buttons.

**EDIT:** I am using Wordpress so all the javascript is in a separate `.js` file brought in

Comment: You mean toggle?

Comment: this can be done by toggling b/t two classes using jquery

Comment: yes, I guess I should have used that terminology a bit more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `toggleNav` function which will alternative between executing both your `openNav` and `closeNav` functions by using a boolean like so:

```js
let opened = false; // set the nav as closed by default
function toggleNav() {
  if(!opened) { // if opened is false (ie nav is closed), open the nav
    openNav()
  } else { // else, if opened is ture (ie nav is open), close the nav
    closeNav();
  }
  opened = !opened; // negate boolean to get opposite (t to f, and f to t)
}

function openNav() {
  console.log("Opened Nav");
}

function closeNav() {
  console.log("Closed Nav");
}
```

```html
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" onclick="toggleNav()">Toggle Nav</button>
```

Comment: Should this be wrapped in an $(document).ready or the like since it will be brought in through a separate .js file (Wordpress)

Comment: @user3550879 no this doesn't need to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` as you are using buttons to activate your functions. As nothing in your javascript references HTML when it is _first loaded_ you don't need to worry about `$(document).ready` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) of the element at end of both functions.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('nav-icon');
function openNav(){
  console.log('openNav called');
  btn.onclick = closeNav
}
function closeNav(){
  console.log('closeNav called');
  btn.onclick = openNav
}
```

```html
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" onclick="openNav()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically have something like:

```
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" onclick="toggleNav()"></button>
```

And the JS:

```
var navOpen = false;
function toggleNav(){ 
   navOpen = !navOpen
   // Do conditional show hide here based on navOpen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a line to each of your functions:

In `openNav()`:

```
document.getElementById("nav-icon").setAttribute("onclick", "closeNav()");
```

In `closeNav()`:

```
document.getElementById("nav-icon").setAttribute("onclick", "openNav()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can call the functions based on some flag value:

```js
var flag = true;
var navBtn = document.querySelector('#nav-icon');
navBtn.addEventListener('click', function(btn){
  if(flag) openNav();
  else closeNav();
  flag = !flag;
});

function openNav(){
  console.log('Open');
}

function closeNav(){
  console.log('Close');
}
```

```html
<button id="nav-icon" class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button">Click</button>
```